# Find every instance of @<username> in paragraph in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a paragraph that could have 1 or more instances of "@" followed by different usernames. How can I find each instance of this in Javascript?

Something like this but it doesn't work yet:

```
var regexp = '/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i';
var post = "Hi @tom, where is @john and @nick?" ;
var match, matches = [];

while ((match = regexp.exec(post)) != null) {
    matches.push(match.index);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Console log would read: **@tom @john @nick**

Comment: "Put code here" type questions are too broad for Stack Overflow.  You need to show a substantial attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I'll give you a hint that regular expressions are the thing to read up about: The javascript guide has extensive tutorial on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @tomuky Unfortunately, it is still off-topic.  Saying that it does not work is not enough.  You need to describe the reasons why it does not work.

Comment: @Anonymous If I knew why it doesn't work, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @tomuky No, you misunderstood me.  I meant that you should say something like "This wrongly replaces *this* example text because the result is *this* and I want *this*" or "This code has a syntax error: [Syntax Error Here]."  Then, conclude with "What I have tried to solve this is..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **two** mistakes in your code causing it not to work as you expect.

(`1.`) You need to remove the quotes from your regular expression and use the `g` (global) modifier. You can replace your character class to the shorter version `\w` and remove the case-insensitive modifier here.

```
var regexp = /@\w+/g
```

(`2.`) You need to reference the match instead of referencing the match.`index`

```
matches.push(match[0]);
```

Final solution:

```
var post   = "Hi @tom, where is @john and @nick?";
var regexp = /@\w+/g
var match, matches = [];

while ((match = regexp.exec(post)) != null) {
   matches.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(matches); //=> [ '@tom', '@john', '@nick' ]
```

Alternatively you can use the **String**.[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```
var post   = 'Hi @tom, where is @john and @nick?',
    result = post.match(/@\w+/g);

console.log(result); //=> [ '@tom', '@john', '@nick' ]
```

Comment: @MattCoubrough If you're going to get all upset at people giving answers, you should take a chill pill. What's with all the misplaced anger? Go and dust off your "The beatings will continue until morale improves" poster.

Comment: @tadman, with all due respect, Matt just wants a healthier community overall, and spoonfeeding people with code is not contributing to that. What he actually commented above (hinting about regex) is perfect as he pointed the right direction, however, he let the poster do the research and coding.

Comment: @MarkGabriel Being concerned about that sort of thing is fine, but seeing a perfectly valid answer being severely punished based on someone's opinion of "worthiness" is uncalled for.

Comment: @hwnd The editing of the question and the answer have really improved this as a resource for everyone. Great to see Stack Overflow working... answer upvoted